# Add controller to a Razor Component Library for .Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, nuget, asp.net-core-3.1, razor-component-library

I am migrating to MVC Core 3.1 and thankfully it wasn't that hard until I had to migrate the RCL.

Within the RCL I am including some common controllers and in order to use the `Controller` base class and `IActionResult` type I was using the Nuget `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstraction` but it's only available for .net Core 2.2.

Why I cannot find the newer version 3.1 in the Nuget repository?

When I navigate to the definition of `IActionResult` I am shown a file with version 3.1.0 so I suppose there should be a way to reference that instead of 2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project was based on `NetStandard2.0` and I manually changed that to `netcoreapp3.1` plus adding the reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`.

```
<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
```

To been able to use `Controllers` and any other feature of the MVC framework on 3.1

- Create a RCL project
- Edit the `.csProj` file and make the appropriate changes to look like that:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RazorLangVersion>3.0</RazorLangVersion>
    <AddRazorSupportForMvc>true</AddRazorSupportForMvc>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web" Version="3.1.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```